# Gremlin can't seem to query by node property

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin

I can't get Gremlin to do basic queries.

```
=> curl --data-urlencode "script=g.v(3)" http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script 
=> 
{
  "extensions" : {
  },
  "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships/out",
  "labels" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/labels",
  "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
  "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/traverse/{returnType}",
  "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3",
  "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/properties/{key}",
  "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
  "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/properties",
  "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships/in",
  "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships",
  "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
  "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships/all",
  "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
  "metadata" : {
    "id" : 3,
    "labels" : [ "node" ]
  },
  "data" : {
    "node_name" : "test_node",
    "email_address" : "test@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

So we can see that the data is there, and it has the "node_name" property which is set to "test_node". Now, when we try to use Gremlin to find that node...

```
=> curl --data-urlencode "script=g.V('node_name','test_node')" http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script
=> []
```

Nothing shows up. What's going on?

Neo Version: 2.1.7

Gremlin Version: neo4j-gremlin-plugin-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, straight from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin

Java Version: 
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: What does `g.V().has('node_name','test_node')` return out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

As D.Mill pointed out, the correct Gremlin syntax is:

```
g.V().has("node_name", "test_node")
```